# I can't invoke setValue on a background thread and keep observe functionality

Tags: multithreading, android-livedata, android-handler

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread`

I get the above error when I try to use setvalue:

`data.setValue(arrayListLogReturn);`

I understand that I can change this to postvalue, but then I lose observe functionality on the livedata.

`data.postValue(arrayListLogReturn);`

My question is how do I keep observe functionality and update the value ? Any help would be appreciated.